# Is there any other way to get content to Firebase Hosting / CDN other than using the Node.js "Firebase deploy" command line tool?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-tools

I only ask because I'm using a shared hosting environment at the moment and they don't support Node.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only documented way to deploy content to Firebase Hosting is to use the [Firebase command line interface](https://www.firebase.com/docs/hosting/command-line-tool.html).